# summarize a table based on certain features in one column

Tags: perl

I tried to summarize the following table based a the same features in column 1:

infile:

```
A       m
A       m
A       n
A       n
A       m
A       c
A       m
A       i
A       n
A       n
B       n
B       n
B       n
B       n
B       n
B       n
C       o
C       i
C       q
```

I wrote the following code, but I do not know why it does not report the last feature

perl code.pl 1 2 infile

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $col_feature         = $ARGV[0];
my $col_to_be_collapsed = $ARGV[1];

my $infile = $ARGV[2];

open( my $fh1, "<$infile" );

my $temp;
my $line_count = 0;
my %count      = ();
my @array      = ();

while ( my $line = <$fh1> ) {
    chomp($line);

    my @line            = split( "\t| ", $line );
    my $to_be_collapsed = $line[ $col_to_be_collapsed - 1 ];
    my $feature         = $line[ $col_feature - 1 ];

    if ( $line_count >= 1 && $temp ne '' ) {

        my @temp                 = split( "\t| ", $temp );
        my $to_be_collapsed_temp = $temp[ $col_to_be_collapsed - 1 ];
        my $feature_temp         = $temp[ $col_feature - 1 ];

        if ( $feature_temp eq $feature ) {
            push( @array, $to_be_collapsed );
        }

        else {
            map { $count{$_}++ } @array;
            print "$feature_temp:\t";
            print "$_:$count{$_}\t" foreach sort { $a cmp $b } keys %count;

            %count = ();
            @array = ();
            $temp  = $line;

            push( @array, $to_be_collapsed );
            print "\n";
        }
    }

    else {
        $temp = $line;
        push( @array, $to_be_collapsed );
    }
    $line_count++;
}

#print $temp,"\n";
```

output:

```
A:      c:1     i:1     m:4     n:4
B:      n:6
```

But there is no any report for C in the first column!!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be alot easier to use a hash in this particular case as you just need to keep a counter.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

#open my $fh, '<', 'infile';       # Uncomment for live file.
my $fh = \*DATA;                  # For testing only.

my %counter;

while (<$fh>) {
    my ( $outerkey, $innerkey ) = split;
    $counter{$outerkey}{$innerkey}++;
}

for my $outerkey ( sort keys %counter ) {
    print "$outerkey:";
    print "\t$_:$counter{$outerkey}{$_}" for sort keys %{ $counter{$outerkey} };
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
A       m
A       m
A       n
A       n
A       m
A       c
A       m
A       i
A       n
A       n
B       n
B       n
B       n
B       n
B       n
B       n
C       o
C       i
C       q
```

#### Output:

```
A:  c:1 i:1 m:4 n:4
B:  n:6
C:  i:1 o:1 q:1
```

Comment: tnx @jaypal, how about processing a huge file? I thought if I save all in a hash it needs a lots of memory. Am I correct?

Comment: @EpiMan since we are only storing counts of unique keys this will be far more efficient than an array based solution.